# Dojo DataGrid (EnhancedGrid) sorting issue

Tags: sorting, dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid

I have a DataGrid, created programmatically and loaded from ItemFileReadStore. 
I want the first column of DataGrid always be sorted in descending order and disabled for user for sorting. Any other column should be available for sorting as a secondary sortable.

I don't want to give users such a powerful(complex and confusing) feature, as sorting by multiple columns, because there are too many columns in my grid.

So, it should be one sortable column for user and another one "already sorted unsortable" column in fact.

Does anyone know how can this be achieved?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To sort the first column add "sortInfo:-1" when you created your object.

To allow sorting the grid from any other columns but not the first you need to overwrite the function canSort.
To create you grid should now look like this .

```
dijit.grid.DataGrid({
  canSort: function (sortInfo) {
                if (Math.abs(sortInfo) == 1){
                    return false;
                } else {
                    return this.inherited("canSort", arguments);
                }
            },
  sortInfo: -1,    .....
```

If you need to sort on more as one column you need  dojox.grid.enhanced.plugins.NestedSorting.
http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojox/grid/EnhancedGrid/plugins/NestedSorting.html

Comment: First, thank you for response! This code works great, but after rendering the grid, when I try to sort any column the "already sorted unsortable" column became "not sorted unsortable". 

Obviously, I should use EnhancedGrid with nestedSorting. But as I mentioned earlier, there are a lot of columns in the grid and I don't want user to be confused with that "1,2,3,4..." nested sorting stuff. It should be simple ascending/descending sorting by 1 column (for user!!).

Got any thoughts?